# Redirect to default image when file is not found

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

From an iOS app I upload small avatars of Apple Game Center users to a web server, into an `/ios-avatars/` dir.

But some players do not have any pictures.

By using Apache mod_rewrite is it please possible to redirect "not found" requests to files like `/ios-avatars/GC123456789.png` to `/images/default.png`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need a rewrite for that. Just use an `ErrorDocument`...

```
<Location /ios-avatars/>
    ErrorDocument 404 /images/default.png
</Location>
```